# How to display related objects through DetailView

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display a product, and available brands(has product as ForeignKey) for that product through DetailView. Based on Django documentation and similar answers on stackoverflow, I tried below code but it doesn't work. Product details are rendering but names of brands are not. I've checked through django-admin, that the brands the products are present in the database.
Could someone please help.

**Models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.IntegerField()
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='Brands')
```

**Views.py**

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
```

Urls.py

```
path('detail/<int:pk>/',views.ProductDetailView.as_view(),name='product_detail'),
```

**product_detail.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-secondary">
  <tr>
    <th class="bg-secondary th-customer-detail">Name</th>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="bg-secondary th-customer-detail">Price</th>
    <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br>
<ul>
  {% for brand in product.brand_set.all %}
      <li>{{ brand.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  #returns a dictionary of context
        primary_key = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        brands = Brand.objects.filter(product = primary_key)
        new_context_objects = {'brands':brands}
        context.update(new_context_objects)
        return context


<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-secondary">
  <tr>
    <th class="bg-secondary th-customer-detail">Name</th>
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="bg-secondary th-customer-detail">Price</th>
    <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<br>
<ul>
  {% for brand in brands %}
      <li>{{brand.name}}</li>
  {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly fine. But I feel accessing related objects is a very trivial use case, and there must be a way to handle them in class based view itself. Would you have any idea regarding that?

Comment: Yes there should be a way to handle them. I tried it but i didn't get any source related to this.